# Can´t install android wear apk automatically from play store

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, wear-os

I have created a demo project of wear in Android studio. So the two projects created automatically, the phone and the Android wear are linked correctly.

When I generate the apk of the phone project, the two apks are generated.

The phone apk I signed it and uploaded it to Google Play Alpha.

In generated phone apk, inside res/raw I can se wear apk. So the mobile apk contains the wearable apk properly.

I have real physical phone and Android wear emulator linked. When I link real device to emulator, in Android wear emulator my phones apps that have wearable version are installed automatically.

I download my app upload from play store alpha to my phone, but in my wear emulator wear version of my app is not installed.

Additional info:

-The wearable emulator does not contain any app with the same package name.

-I have done several tests creating a new emulator.

-In the emulator if I install the application directly with the play button of Android studio works correctly

Comment: If you haven't done so, try to **switch to advanced mode** in your application's **APK files** tab. See [Simple mode and advanced mode](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SimpleAndAdvanced) for more information about toggling between modes.

Answer (score 0):

The [packaging and distribution](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) of wearable apps changed with Android Wear 2.0. Wearable apps are no longer synchronized from the phone. Instead you need to upload a wearable APK to the Play Store.

Comment: I tested with Android Wear 1.X emulator.

Comment: `On devices running Wear 2.0, when a user installs a phone app that has an associated watch app (either an embedded APK or an APK uploaded via the Play Console), the user gets a watch notification about the available watch app. Tapping the notification opens the watch Play Store, giving the user the option to install the watch app.` 

Looks like this is not the case? I have released my Android and WearOS companion apps on Google Play production track but nothing happens when I install the Android app on the phone.

Comment: Moreover, user cannot see that my app has a Wear OS companion app on Google Play listing page. Only if they launch Google Play on their Wear OS device, they can find it out. How could we prompt user to install the app on the watch or automate this process?

Comment: @RomanSamoilenko I think you'd be better off posting this as new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950020/how-to-install-wearos-companion-app-along-with-the-android-phone-app-automatical